# Jaspersoft Studio Custom Component Tutorial

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I've been going through the process of developing a custom [QRCode component for Jaspersoft](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/introduction-custom-components-ireport-designer). This article explains how to do it in [iReport Designer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer).  But I'm wondering how to get the QRCode component described by the article to work in [Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio).

Does anyone have any examples of a custom component that can be used with Jaspersoft Studio?  I'm looking for links to source or tutorials.  Have not been able to find anything specific to Jaspersoft Studio.

Comment: This is a Java programming problem.  An extension to Jaspersoft Studio is a Java component that runs within Eclipse.  It's just not clear to me what contracts I need to implement to get a custom component working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually there is no official documentation on how to create custom components in Jaspersoft Studio.
Moreover, as you may probably have seen, Jaspersoft Studio is based on Eclipse, while iReport is based on Netbeans. Therefore, you will need to create an Eclipse plugin for it, so you should start looking at how to develop Eclipse plug-ins first.

We are planning to develop a custom wizard in order to allow the user to create the needed skeleton to create a custom component. The same will be for custom data adapters. Somehow it will follow the same idea we implemented with the "Functions Library" wizard, introduced in the last versions.

Unfortunately there is still no timeline for this. Highly probably it will be included in the next major release.

However, you could give a look at how the HTML component is currently implemented in Jaspersoft Studio. I think it's a good candidate from where to start.

Check:

- HTML JR component source code in the demo folder of JasperReports project
- HTML JSS component source code in the plug-in com.jaspersoft.studio.html

Best regards,
Massimo.